# Play store in app purchase product maximum limit

Tags: android, google-play

I know iOS has a maximum number of 10.000 in app purchase products. Does anyone know if there is a similar limit in the google play store?

Comment: It is powered by google wallet. And Google Wallet has a daily spending limit of $1,000. So an user will not be able to purchase more than $1000 from your app per day. That's the only limit I can see.

Comment: @Calvin: Maybe I wasn't clear, but I'm not talking from a customer's point of view. But simply how much in-app purchases I (as developer) can create in the google play dashboard.

Comment: How much product ids, we can create in play store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit in Google Play, or if there is it is not publicly documented.

On another note, why would you possible need 10000 in app products?

Comment: If I want to sell newspapers, what do you suggest? Consumable items?

Answer (score 9):

Raghavs answer is incorrect. At least incorrect to the current Google Play console. The current store has a limit of 1000 in-app products.

[image: Google Play Console In-App product limit]

Comment: And whats about the in-app subscription max limit?